# Has the Syrian (Baath) government issued any public statements on desired post-war relations with Rojava?

Tags: syria

In the Syrian Civil War, Rojava and Syria have had a ["tacit alliance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rojava%E2%80%93Syria_relations).  A Rojavan spokesperson declared their desire for a federal government.  Rojava is supported by the US and Russia and opposed by Turkey; the government is supported by Iran, Russia and opposed by the US and Turkey.  That makes for a delicate situation, even after the Civil War finishes.

The Syrian Arab Republic wants to wipe out Tahrir al-Sham, Islamic State, and Syrian National Council, perhaps with the option of negotiations for the latter.  They're been fighting intensively with all three.  But they haven't fought too much with Rojava.  Have there been any public statements from the Syrian Arab Republic government on what kind of post-war relationship they may consider with Rojava?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They repeatedly reiterate that they do not consider any opportunity of recognizing secession of Syrian regions. They stand fast for the territorial integrity of Syria. I think this stance is to a high degree influenced by Iran.

Comment: AFAIK Rojava does not desire secession. From linked enwiki, Rojava stance is: *We believe that a federal system is ideal form of governance for Syria. We see that in many parts of the world, a federal framework enables people to live peacefully and freely within territorial borders. The people of Syria can also live freely in Syria. We will not allow for Syria to be divided; all we want is the democratization of Syria; its citizens must live in peace, and enjoy and cherish the ethnic diversity of the national groups inhabiting the country.*. Does that conflict with Syrian stance?